# How to call Barcode Scanner in Webview, and passing it back?

Tags: android, android-webview, barcode-scanner

I have following scenario:

1. Click a link or button.
2. Open up Barcode Scanner by ZXing.
3. Scan the code.
4. Pass the decoded data to other webpages.

For 1 and 4, it must be performed inside WebView. The problem I faced was, using this https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages, I will be opening the webpage in default browser. Should I use Intent instead to overcome this problem? Or there are any better workaround?

Comment: Ops, should have used 'invoke' instead of 'call', well....the problem using callback URL as stated in the link of my question, is it will open up default browser for the URL, rather than the WebView that invoke the barcode scanner.

Comment: I have to do some thing like yours. can you please post the answer here. I will be thank full to you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Successfully got it working, need put add code to call Intent in JavascriptInterface, and the onActivityResult to retrieve decoded contents should not be put inside JavascriptInterface.

Sample code:

```
public class MainView extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    public static String barcode = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);    //you might need to change webView1

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
    } // onCreate();

    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        // Instantiate the interface and set the context
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        // using Javascript to call the finish activity
        public void closeMyActivity() {
            finish();
        }

        public void scanBarcode() {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }   //JavascriptInterface

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //here is where you get your result
                barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In your Javascript:

```
function scan(){
    Android.scanBarcode();
}
```

Comment: I have to do some thing like yours. can you please post the answer here. I will be thank full to you. :)

Comment: @QadirHussain I have added code sample for you, you might need to tweak a little cause I have cut out some minor code.

Comment: @TanJiaMing...Did you implement this in iOS as well?? Does it work in iOS??

Comment: @subha no, I have not implement this in iOS, and I have not involve in mobile app programming after this pet project, so I can't help you further.